# Creating an Azure VM with powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to create an Azure VM with Windows 10 pro with the following command but I am unable.

New-AzVm `-ResourceGroupName "lab2023"`
-Name 'vmlab' `-Location "canadacentral"`
-Image "win10-22h2-pro" `-VirtualNetworkName "lab2023-vnet"`
-SubnetName "lab2023-subnet" `-SecurityGroupName 'labvm-nsg'`
-PublicIpAddressName 'vm-ip' `
-OpenPorts 3389

I receive this error
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dhA8.png)]

I am trying to find the name of the image, but no luck.

I want to make it very easy command to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Image` parameter is a structured value built up from several pieces of information as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage):

> Now you can combine the selected publisher, offer, SKU, and version into a URN (values separated by :). Pass this URN with the -Image parameter when you create a VM with the New-AzVM cmdlet. You can also replace the version number in the URN with latest to get the latest version of the image.

Some examples of image urns are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-manage-vm#understand-marketplace-images) although I cannot find one for Windows 10, and the resulting command looks like:

`New-AzVm` 
-ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupVM" `-Name "myVM2"`
-Location "EastUS" `-VirtualNetworkName "myVnet"`
-SubnetName "mySubnet" `-SecurityGroupName "myNetworkSecurityGroup"`
-PublicIpAddressName "myPublicIpAddress2" `-ImageName "MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2016-Datacenter-with-Containers:latest"`
-Credential $cred  `-AsJob`